# Vue warn]: Property or method "options" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.Vue js issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Having an error when rendreing the project. I have checked all details but couldnt find the which line is causing the issue. The console says
Vue warn]: Property or method "options" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
Here is what I tried.

navbar.vue

```
<template>
 <div id="navbar">   
    <nav id="sidebar">
      <ul class="list-unstyled components">
          <p></p>
          <div id="dismiss">
              <i class="fas fa-times left"></i>
          </div>
          <li id="active" class="active">
            <a id="active"><i class="fa-fw fas fa-book fa-xs"></i> Программы</a>
                   <ul  id="homeSubmenu">
                                 <li>
                      <a href="en-beginner.html">Английский для начинающих</a>
                  </li>
                 <!--  <li>
                      <a href="#">Английский для среднего уровня</a>
                  </li> -->
                  <li>
                      <a href="https://ahoyla.com/ielts">Подготовка к IELTS</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li  class="active">
            <a id="active"><i class="fa-fw fas fa-user-graduate fa-xs"></i>Обучение</a>
            <ul id="pageSubmenu">
                <li>
                    <a class="off-canvas-item" href="https://lms.ahoyla.com/english-beginners">Начальный уровень</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="off-canvas-item" href="https://lms.ahoyla.com/english-intermediate">Средний уровень</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="off-canvas-item" href="https://lms.ahoyla.com/ielts-course-1">IELTS</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
                                
          </li>
          <li class="active">
              <a href="https://ahoyla.com/"><img class="li-image" src="../assets/images/ahoyla.png" width="20" height="15">Метод обучения Ahoyla</a>
          </li>
          <li class="active">
              <a href="https://lms.ahoyla.com/plans-pricing"><img class="li-image" src="../assets/images/ahoyla.png" width="20" height="12">Тарифные планы</a>
          </li>
           </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="overlay"></div>
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-transparent">
        <router-link to="/">
            <a style="width: auto;" class="navbar-brand" id="navbar-desktop">
         <img id class="navbar-image" src="../assets/images/logo.svg" alt="log">
        </a></router-link> 
      <button style="background: transparent; color: black; border: none;" type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="mobile-menu">
      <span style="background: transparent;" class="fas fa-bars"></span>
      </button>
      <router-link to="/">
        <a style="width: 180px;" class="navbar-brand" id="navbar-mobile">
          <img class="navbar-image" src="../assets/images/logo.svg" alt="log">
             </a></router-link> 
               <li id="nav-link" class="nav-item" href="https://www.lms.ahoyla.com/login">
                    <a style="color: inherit;" href="https://www.lms.ahoyla.com/login"> <i class="fas fa-user-circle fa-lg"  ></i></a>
                          </li>
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <router-link to="/beginner"><li class="nav-item dropdown active">
     <a class="nav-link" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
       aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
       Программы
     </a>
    </li></router-link> 
    <li class="nav-item dropdown active">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
       aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
       Обучение
     </a>
 
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item active">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#">Тестирование <span
         class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
     <li class="nav-item">
    
      <a style="color: inherit;" href="https://www.lms.ahoyla.com/login"> <i class="fas fa-user-circle fa-lg"></i></a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item active">
       <a class="nav-link">Your Bookings</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
      </div>    
    </nav>
 </div>
</template>


<script>
import $ from 'jquery'

export default {
        name:'navbar',
  mounted(){   
let sidebar = document.createElement('script')
 sidebar.setAttribute('src', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js')
 document.head.appendChild(sidebar)
$(document).ready(function(){$("#sidebar")
.mCustomScrollbar({theme:"minimal"})
,$("#dismiss, .overlay")
.on("click",function(){$("#sidebar")
.removeClass("active"),$(".overlay")
.removeClass("active")}),$("#sidebarCollapse")
.on("click",function(){$("#sidebar")
.addClass("active"),$(".overlay")
.addClass("active"),$(".collapse.in")
.toggleClass("in"),$("a[aria-expanded=true]")
.attr("aria-expanded","false")})});

    },
    
}
</script>


Beginner.vue


<template>
    <div>
  <div class="beginnerEnglish">
   <div class="container">
   <div class="navbarArea" id="navbarArea">
      <white-navbar/>
    <div class="InitialContent">
    <h1 class="bannerHeader">Заговори на английском за 30 дней</h1>
    <h2 class="h2Header">Занимайтесь с сильными преподавателями от <br/>1 000тг за занятие</h2>
    <button class="SeeTheCourse">Начать заниматься</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="comfortEnglish">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="container-width">
        <h1 class="comfortHeader" style="margin-bottom: 50px;">Выбирайте комфортный английский</h1>      
 <flickity  class="carousel" ref="flickity" :options="flickityOptions"> 
<div class="carousel-cell text-center"> 
  <div class="inner">
    <span style="color:#55C4C6" class="fas fa-comments fa-2x"></span>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5  style="color:#55C4C6" class="card-title">Обучение через общение</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Максимум разговорной практики - вы будете говорить уже с первого урока, даже если учите английский с нуля.</p>  
         </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-cell text-center">
    <div class="inner">
    <span style="color:#55C4C6" class="fas fa-bullseye fa-2x"></span>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5  style="color:#55C4C6" class="card-title">Приводим к цели</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Помогаем заговорить на английском, сдать экзамены, поступить в вуз и улучшить навыки английского языка.</p>  
     
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="carousel-cell text-center">
    <div class="inner">
    <span style="color:#55C4C6" class="fas fa-smile fa-2x"></span>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5  style="color:#55C4C6" class="card-title">Учитываем интересы</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Добавляем в уроки фильмы с субтитрами, книги, игры, комиксы. Подаем контент не скучно.</p>  
     
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</flickity>
</div>
       </div>
        </div>  

         <div  class="headLiner2" id="headLine">
    <div class="container-fluid  h-100">
    
            <div class="headlinerCenter text-center ml-auto mr-auto">
                <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center justify-content-center h-100 ">
                 <div class="col-md-12">
                  <h2 class="blackHeader">Записывайтесь на бесплатную консультацию</h2>
                  <h2 class="whiteHeader">Познакомим со школой и покажем, как проходят занятия</h2>
                  <button class="register">Записаться</button>
                </div>
               
              </div>

         
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
   <div class="comfortEnglish" id="comforEnglish2">
    <div class="container-fluid justify-content-end">
         <h1 class="comfortHeader" id="comfortHeader" style="margin-bottom: 50px;">Что вы получите</h1>
       
<flickity class="carousel" ref="flickity" :options="flickityOptions">
          <div class="carousel-cell text-center"  style="background-color: azure;"> 
                <span style="color:#55C4C6" class="fas fa-user-graduate fa-2x"></span>
                <div class="card-body">
                <h5 style="color:#55C4C6" class="card-title">Уникальная методика</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Наши методики, помогают преодолеть языковой барьер и помогают вывести вас на новый уровень</p>  
             </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-cell text-center" style="background-color: azure;">
              <span style="color:#55C4C6" class="fas fa-heartbeat fa-2x"></span>
              <div class="card-body">
              <h5  style="color:#55C4C6" class="card-title">Приводим к цели</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Посещай онлайн лекции с преподавателем, задавай все интересующие вопросы.</p>  
             
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-cell text-center" style="background-color: azure;">
              <span style="color:#55C4C6" class="fas fa-user-check fa-2x"></span>
              <div class="card-body">
              <h5  style="color:#55C4C6" class="card-title">Учитываем интересы</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Подстраиваемся под ваши потребности и адаптируем учебные материалы под ваши задачи</p>  
             </div>
        </div>
        </flickity>
</div>
  </div>

  <div class="midContent">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="pinkContent ml-auto mr-auto">
    <div class="d-flex no-gutters align-content-start flex-wrap">
    <div class="image" id="image">
      <img src="../assets/images/coaching.png">   
     </div>
        <div class="word">
  <h1>онлайн дешевле чем офлайн</h1>
 <p class="pinkContentparagraph">Наши цены в 2 раза ниже, чем у оффлайн-репетиторов. Почему? Все просто: наши преподаватели английского не тратят время на дорогу к Вам!</p>
  <button class="SeeTheCourse">Начать заниматься</button>



  <p class="lowerParagraph"> <span class="fas fa-thumbs-up fa-fw"></span>Кроме того, не забывайте, что у нас в Ahoyla Вы можете пройти множество бесплатных пробных уроков, чтобы найти своего репетитора (разве такое возможно оффлайн?).
    </p> 
    <p class="lowerParagraph2"><b>Английский онлайн с Ahoyla — это выгодно</b></p>
    </div>
 

  </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="prices">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="comfortHeader" id="comfortHeader" style="margin-bottom: 50px;">Наши цены</h1>
    <div class="d-flex row no-gutters justify-content-center">
  <div class="card text-center mt-3">
  <div class="card-body">
   <h5 class="card-title">10 Уроков</h5>
    <h5 id="biggerSize" class="card-title" style="font-weight: bold; padding-bottom:5px;padding-top:15px;">1 600 <span class="fas fa-tenge d-inline-block"></span></h5>
    <p id="card-height" class="card-text">за урок</p>
    <p class="card-text">Всего к оплате 16 000тг </p>
   
    <button class="SeeTheCourse mt-5">Начать заниматься</button>
    <a class="collapsed d-lg-none d-md-block" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-collapsed" aria-controls="collapse-collapsed" id="body-collapsed">
      <span class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-bottom"></span>
  </a>
  <div id="collapse-collapsed" class="collapse d-lg-block" aria-labelledby="body-collapsed">
   <p id="lowerbodyparagraph" class="card-text">10 онлайн уроков</p>
   <p id="lowerbodyparagraph" class="card-text">Интерактивные задания</p>
   <p id="lowerbodyparagraph" class="card-text" style="border-bottom: none;" >Безлимитный доступ к материалам</p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card text-center mt-3">
  <div class="card-body">
   <h5  class="card-title" >30 Уроков</h5>
    <h5 id="biggerSize" class="card-title d-inline-block" style="font-weight: bold; padding-bottom:5px;padding-top:15px;">1 300<span class="fas fa-tenge d-inline-block"></span></h5>
    <p id="card-height" class="card-text">за урок</p>
    <p class="card-text">Всего к оплате 39 000тг </p>
    <p class="economyTariff">Сэкономить 9 000 тг</p>
    <button class="SeeTheCourse">Начать заниматься</button>
    <a class="collapsed d-lg-none d-md-block" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-collapsed2" aria-controls="collapse-collapsed2" id="body-collapsed">
      <span class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-bottom fa-md"></span>
  </a>
  <div id="collapse-collapsed2" class="collapse d-lg-block" aria-labelledby="body-collapsed">
   <p id="lowerbodyparagraph" class="card-text">30 онлайн уроков</p>
   <p id="lowerbodyparagraph"  class="card-text">Интерактивные задания</p>
   <p id="lowerbodyparagraph" class="card-text" style="border-bottom: none;">Безлимитный доступ к материалам</p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card text-center mt-3">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="sale">
      Лучший выбор!
    </div>
   <h5 class="card-title">60 Уроков</h5>
    <h5 id="biggerSize" style="color: #2FAFE5;font-weight: bold; padding-bottom:5px;padding-top:15px;" class="card-title">1 000 <span class="fas fa-tenge d-inline-block"></span></h5>
    <p id="card-height" class="card-text">за урок</p>
    <p class="card-text">Всего к оплате 60 000тг</p>
    <p class="economyTariff">Сэкономить 16 000 тг</p>
    <button class="SeeTheCourse">Начать заниматься</button>
    <a class="collapsed d-lg-none d-md-block" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-collapsed3" aria-controls="collapse-collapsed3" id="body-collapsed">
      <span class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-bottom"></span>
  </a>
  <div id="collapse-collapsed3" class="collapse d-lg-block" aria-labelledby="body-collapsed">
   <p id="lowerbodyparagraph" class="card-text">60 онлайн уроков</p>
   <p id="lowerbodyparagraph" class="card-text">Премиальная поддержка</p>
   <p id="lowerbodyparagraph" class="card-text">Обратная связь</p>
   <p id="lowerbodyparagraph" class="card-text" style="border-bottom: none;">Безлимитный доступ к материалам</p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="policy">
<div class="container">
  <div class="d-flex row  justify-content-center">
  <div class="p-2">
 <span class="fas fa-user-shield d-inline-block"></span>
</div>
<div class="p-2">
<h4>Безопасная оплата</h4>
<p class="d-inline-block">Все транзакции будут обрабатываться через соединение с шифрованием SSL.</p>
</div>
 <div class="p-2">
  <span class="fas fa-undo d-inline-block"></span>
 </div>
 
 <div class="p-2">
 <h4>30-дневная гарантия возврата денег</h4>
 <p class="d-inline-block">Все транзакции будут обрабатываться через соединение с шифрованием SSL..</p>
 </div>
</div>
</div>   
  </div>
    <div class="feedbacks" id="feedbacks">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <h1 class="comfortHeader" id="comfortHeader">Отзывы</h1>
      <div id="container-width">
      <flickity style="margin-top: 50px;" class="carouselLeft2" ref="flickity" :options="flickityOptions2">
          <div class="cell">     
  <vue-plyr :options="options">
   <video playsinline  data-poster="poster.jpg"  class="js-player">
  <source size="720" src="../assets/videos/video.mp4"  type="video/mp4"/>
      </video>
    </vue-plyr>     
        <h3>Саша</h3>
      </div>
     <div class="cell">
   <vue-plyr :options="options">
   <video playsinline  data-poster="poster.jpg"  class="js-player">
       <source size="720" src="../assets/videos/video2.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
      </video>
    </vue-plyr> 
      <!-- <video playsinline controls data-poster="/path/to/poster.jpg">
        <source src="../assets/videos/video2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
         </video> -->
       <h3>Миранда</h3>
      </div>
    <div class="cell">
   <vue-plyr :options="options">
 <video playsinline  data-poster="poster.jpg"  class="js-player">  
      <source size="720" src="../assets/videos/video3.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
      </video>
    </vue-plyr> 
    <!-- <video   playsinline controls data-poster="/path/to/poster.jpg">
        <source src="../assets/videos/video3.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
       </video> -->
       <h3>Матвей</h3>
</div>
<div class="cell">
  <vue-plyr :options="options">
  <video playsinline  data-poster="poster.jpg"  class="js-player"> 
      <source size="720" src="../assets/videos/video4.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
      </video>
    </vue-plyr> 
<!-- <video  playsinline controls data-poster="/path/to/poster.jpg">
  <source src="../assets/videos/video4.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
 </video> -->
 <h3>Болат</h3>
</div>
      </flickity>
         <div class="control-buttons">
    <span @click="previous()" style="margin-top: 0;" class=" fas fa-angle-left" id="testimonialbtn"></span>
    <span @click="next()" style="margin-left: 20px;" class="fas fa-angle-right" id="testimonialbtn"></span>
  </div>
    </div>
 
  </div>
</div>
  
<div class="headLiner">
  <div class="container-fluid  h-100">
       <div class="headlinerConsultation text-center mx-auto">
              <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center  h-100 ">
               <div class="col">
                <h2 class="whiteHeader">Нужна консультация?</h2>
                <h2 class="greyHeader">Записывайся на консультацию и получи 20% скидки на первый месяц обучения!
                </h2>
                <button class="register">Получить скидку</button>
              </div>
            </div>
             </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="faq">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="container-width">
    <h1>FAQ</h1>
    <ul class="accordion-list">
      <li>
        <h3>Что нужно что бы приступить к занятиям?</h3>
        <div class="answer">
          <p>Для этого нужен компьютер, планшет или телефон. Уроки проходят онлайн и для подключения к живому уроку вам нужно зарегистрироваться в нашей платформе.</p>
       </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3>Есть ли в возрастные ограничения?</h3>
        <div class="answer"><p>Нет, мы разделяем только по уровню владения английским. У нас занимаются и дети и взрослые. </p></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3>Сколько длится занятие?</h3>
        <div class="answer"><p>Продолжительность одного урока 1 академический час. Мы делаем уроки насыщенными и ёмкими, чтобы тебе легко было выделить время на занятия и нагрузка была посильной. </p></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3>Когда я могу начать?</h3>
        <div class="answer"><p>Начать вы можете в любое время! Наши преподаватели всегда готовы и ждут новых студентов. </p></div>
      </li>
   
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div> 
<Footer/>
    </div>
</template>







<script>

import Footer from '@/components/Footer.vue'
import whiteNavbar from '@/components/whiteNavbar.vue'
import Flickity from 'vue-flickity'
import $ from 'jquery'


export default {
  
name: 'beginner',
  components: {
     whiteNavbar,
     Footer,
     Flickity,
   
  },
  data(){
return{
    flickityOptions: {
       contain:true,
      prevNextButtons: false,
      pageDots: false,
      wrapAround: false,
    },
      flickityOptions2: {
     cellAlign:"center",
    wrapAround:true,
     prevNextButtons: false,
      pageDots: false,
     
    }
}
  },
   
    mounted () {

           this.$refs.plyr.player.on('event', () => console.log('event fired'))
     
$(".plyr__controls").hide();
$(".plyr__control--overlaid").click(function() { 
    $(".plyr__controls").show();});


  
  
  },


   methods: {
    next() {
      this.$refs.flickity.next();
    },    
    previous() {
      this.$refs.flickity.previous();
    }
},
  




}


</script>
```

Comment: `<vue-plyr :options="options">` ... where is the data variable `options` defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines containing `="options"` are causing the error. You don't have such a method, data or computed property in your `script` block but referenced that in your `template`.